# Component variable in template inaccessible

Tags: angular

I have a variable that I got from an API. I want to show it in my template (in the same component) but it only shows me something like this:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
//
//
// // //
//
//
//
```

This is what I try in my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of airport">
    <div *ngFor="let i of item">
        {{ i }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I try to print the variable with `console.log`, the value is just like I expected:

```
// code
console.log(this.airport);
console.log(this.airport[0]);
console.log(this.airport[0][0]);
console.log(this.airport[0][0]['airportCode']);
console.log(typeof this.airport[0][0]);

// output
Array [ Array[51], Array[47] ]
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 41 more… ]
Object { airlineCode: "JT*", airlineLogoUrlPng: "http://d3brl4nqahsb3e.cloudfront.ne…", airlineLogoUrlSvg: "http://d3brl4nqahsb3e.cloudfront.ne…", airlineName: "Lion Air", airportCode: "BPN", airportName: "Sultan Aji Muhamad Sulaiman Airport", city: "Balikpapan", currentDate: "11/04/2016", currentGateDate: "11/04/2016", currentGateTime: "19:05", 31 more… }
BPN
Object
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or maybe there is something that I don't know in angular2?

Comment: What if you do `{{ i | json }}`? But do you actually want to display the JSON string on your page? Why don't you have a component to display it in a more user-friendly manner?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought the object will print json string automatically just like int the console. This is my first time to here that ` |  json ` thing, that help me a lot when debugging, thank you so much. I usually iterate variable in the template, that's what I did in Jinja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are referring to object, object contains properties. So you have to use `object.property` syntax as follow,

```
{{ i.airlineCode })
```

Or

```
{{ i.airlineLogoUrlPng }}
```

and so on.

Comment: Yes, that's the only way I know too.
It's just I can't figure out what's the actual value from the variable, but thanks to @jonrsharpe, now I can finally see it.